# accesing static variable in php

Tags: php, function, static, getter

i have a simple case of class with static variable and a get function 
all compile ok  but at run time i am getting this error

```
[Sun Jul 25 03:57:07 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'TYPE' in .....
```

for the function getType()

here is my class

```
class NoSuchRequestHandler implements Handler{
    public static $TYPE  = 2001;
    public static $VER   = 0;

    public function getType(){
      return self::TYPE;
    }

    public function getVersion(){
      return self::VER;
    }
}
```

thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access this two ways since it is public...

```
class NoSuchRequestHandler implements Handler{
    public static $TYPE  = 2001;
    public static $VER   = 0;

    public function getType(){
        return self::$TYPE;  //not the "$" you were missing.  
    }

    public function getVersion(){
        return self::$VER;
    }
}

echo NoSuchRequestHandler::$TYPE; //outside of the class.
```

Answer (score 7):

PHP thinks you're trying to access a class constant because of:

```
return self::TYPE;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

As Chris mentions, use:

```
return self::$TYPE;
```

Comment: I think you pointed here better what's the mistake. Thank's it helped me too :)

Answer (score 0):

probably the confusing issue is about that a variable of non-static class

```
$myClass->anyVar //here there is no $ character for class variable
```

but for static class

```
MYCLASS::$anyVar  // you must use the $ char for class variable
```